# Local IP range unreachable outside of VM scope (yet same subnet)

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, microk8s

Using Ubuntu 21.10 on both Host and VMs, I'm experiencing networking issues on the following setup:

I have 3 microk8s clusters running on hosts using KVM.
Each cluster has a controller plane and 2 workers nodes, representing 3 VMs. Each VM shares the host network through bridging.
For instance:

- Host has 192.168.10.10
- VM1 (control plane) has 192.168.10.20
- VM2 (worker1) has 192.168.10.21
- VM3 (worker2) has 192.168.10.22

I have setup the metallb service to provide IPs from the range 192.168.10.30 to 192.168.10.39.

I have set up an ingress controller with externalTrafficPolicy set to local and using 192.168.10.30

From VM1, VM2 or VM3, I am able to reach 192.168.10.30 with HTTPS.

However, from the host 192.168.10.10 or any device connected to 192.168.10.0/24, I am not able to reach 192.168.10.30.

What would have I been missing?

Best Regards,

Comment: Hello. I do not see any version of Ubuntu mentioned in your question. If you are using Ubuntu what version is it?

Comment: Thank you! I will edit OP, I'm using ubuntu 21.10